# Site not displaying correctly when re-directing from root to sub-directory

Tags: plugins, css, htaccess, server

I've created a WordPress version of our site in a subdirectory on our server and wish to re-direct from the root to the subdirectory, like:

**mydomain.net**
to
**mydomain.net/wordpress**

For some reason, when I re-direct the main domain to the subdirectory in cPanel or .htaccess, WordPress does not display the site correctly. All of the CSS I've added in the custom CSS plugin disappears. Plugin is "WP Add Custom CSS".

This only happens when I re-direct from mydomain.net, when I re-direct from mydomain.net/index.php for example, WordPress displays fine.

What could be causing the plugin to fail?

Comment: Your WordPress install is in the root and not the subfolder. Can you check this?

Comment: I installed it in the sub-directory.

Comment: Then probably your entire domain is getting redirected to subfolder on the same domain causing an infinite loop, is that the error your getting.

Comment: I was getting the error you described at first, but not anymore. Now it just does what I described above.

Comment: Try to set these constants in your wp-config.php file.

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://sub.example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://sub.example.com' );
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'http://sub.example.com' );

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the entire domain hence breaking the site, because `whole` website is getting redirected to a `part` causing a broken website.

So instead of using .htaccess just create an index.html  file in your root and do a simple [Meta Refresh](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml)

Or

Use [this more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) to do the same using php

Comment: You should use WP core function for redirecting rather than PHP functions - wp_redirect or wp_safe_redirect.

Comment: Using WP core function isn't an option if you don't have WP in the root.